# Redirecting to Display Form from New Form does not save item

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I am attempting to redirect to the Display Form instead of returning to the All Items view when a user saves an item using NewForm.aspx. I am able to accomplish the redirect, but it is not saving the item. My code is as follows and is entered into a Script Editor Web Part on the NewForm.aspx page:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script>
// JavaScript source code
$(document).ready(function() {

var button = $("input[id$=SaveItem]");  
// change redirection behavior  
button.removeAttr("onclick");  
button.click(function() {  
    var elementName = $(this).attr("name");  
    var aspForm = $("form[id=aspnetForm]");  
    var oldPostbackUrl = aspForm.attr("action");  
    //var oldPostbackUrl = aspForm.action;
    var currentSourceValue = GetUrlKeyValue("Source", true, oldPostbackUrl);  
    var newPostbackUrl = oldPostbackUrl.replace(currentSourceValue, "/sites/mysite/DispForm.aspx");  

    if (!PreSaveItem()) return false;  
    WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(elementName, "", true, "", newPostbackUrl, false, true));  
});  
});
</script>
```

Comment: This is within SharePoint 2013 Online.

Comment: UPDATE: It works if you don't pop up into a Modal (List Settings > Advanced > Launch forms in a dialog?). But I need it to pop up in a modal.

Comment: I thought it was working, but certain fields won't save! Please see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25331038/managed-metadata-person-group-and-checkbox-field-values-not-being-saved-on-ite

Comment: You cannot vote on your own post 0 I have it working by conditionally redirecting users once they are returned to the All Items page. Basically, once the default SharePoint save and return to items view is complete, I use the REST API to look for the most recently created item by the current author that does not have it's workflow complete and then redirect to the display form