# Managed Metadata, Person/Group, and Checkbox Field Values Not Being Saved on Item Creation

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint

Managed Metadata, Person/Group, and Checkbox field values are not being saved when I use a very common JavaScript/jQuery redirect method on a New Form. Here is the code that others have referenced in this forum and in blogs. Any clue why these field values are not saving on item creation? I am using SharePoint 2013 Online.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

var button = $("input[id$=SaveItem]");
// change redirection behavior  
button.removeAttr("onclick");
button.click(function () {
    var elementName = $(this).attr("name");
    var aspForm = $("form[id=aspnetForm]");
    var oldPostbackUrl = aspForm.attr("action");
    //var oldPostbackUrl = aspForm.action;
    var currentSourceValue = GetUrlKeyValue("Source", true, oldPostbackUrl);
    var newPostbackUrl = oldPostbackUrl.replace(currentSourceValue, "Redirect.aspx");

    if (!PreSaveItem()) return false;
    WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(elementName, "", true, "", newPostbackUrl, false, true));
});
});
```

Thanks!

K.

Comment: I also tried a "hard redirect" and had the same behavior. Example:     https://me.sharepoint.com/sites/mysite/Lists/mylist/NewForm.aspx?&Source=/sites/mysite/Lists/mylist/RedirectForm.aspx

Comment: You cannot vote on your own post 0 I have it working by conditionally redirecting users once they are returned to the All Items page. Basically, once the default SharePoint save and return to items view is complete, I use the REST API to look for the most recently created item by the current author that does not have it's workflow complete and then redirect to the display form